# unable to extra/list all event log on watson assistant wrokspace

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

Please help I was trying to call watson assistant endpoint
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/myworkspace/logs?version=2018-09-20 to get all the list of events

and filter by date range using this params

```
var param =
{ workspace_id: '{myworkspace}',
page_limit: 100000,
filter: 'response_timestamp%3C2018-17-12,response_timestamp%3E2019-01-01'}
```

apparently I got any empty response below.

```
{
"logs": [],
"pagination": {}
}
```

Comment: What type of account? See https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/logs.html#log-limits

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to check.

1. You have `2018-17-12` which is a metric date. This translates to "12th day of the 17th month of 2018".

2. Assuming the date should be a valid one, your search says "Documents that are Before 17th Dec 2018 and after 1st Jan 2019". Which would return no documents.

3. Logs are only generated when you call the message() method through the API. So check your logging page in the tooling to see if you even have logs.

4. If you have a lite account logs are only stored for 7 days and then deleted. To keep logs longer you need to upgrade to a standard account.

Although not directly related to your issue, be aware that `page_limit` has an upper hard coded limit (IIRC 200-300?). So you may ask for 100,000 records, but it won't give it to you.

---

This is sample python code (unsupported) that is using pagination to read the logs:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import AssistantV1

username = '...'
password = '...'
workspace_id = '....'
url = '...'
version = '2018-09-20'

c = AssistantV1(url=url, version=version, username=username, password=password)

totalpages = 999
pagelimit = 200
logs = []
page_count = 1
cursor = None
count = 0

x = { 'pagination': 'DUMMY' }
while x['pagination']:
    if page_count > totalpages: 
        break

    print('Reading page {}. '.format(page_count), end='')
    x = c.list_logs(workspace_id=workspace_id,cursor=cursor,page_limit=pagelimit)
    if x is None: break

    print('Status: {}'.format(x.get_status_code()))
    x = x.get_result()

    logs.append(x['logs'])
    count = count + len(x['logs'])

    page_count = page_count + 1

    if 'pagination' in x and 'next_url' in x['pagination']:
        p = x['pagination']['next_url']
        u = urlparse(p)
        query = parse_qs(u.query)
        cursor = query['cursor'][0]
```

Your `logs` object should contain the logs.

Comment: thanks @Simon Now I was able to generate the log but the log file content is half populated, So, how do override the hard fcoded  limit in order to be able to extract the full log.

Comment: it's half populated as it uses paging. You have to pull each page. There is no way to override the limit.

Comment: Please I am little bit confuse, do you mean that I will have to pull each page manually or can help with a snippet on out to pull each page

Comment: When you make the first call there is a `pagination` field that will give a URL to the next page. I have some sample code, but need to see if I can release.

Comment: Okay Simon, I'll really appreciate if you can provide me with a sample code snippet.

Comment: There is a node SDK for Watson with examples. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I believe the limit is 500, and then we return a pagination URL so you can get the next 500. I dont think this is the issue but once you start getting logs back its good to know