# Pagination in Watson Assistant api

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to paginate the result from the watson conversation api. But I am unable to do that.

I have tried creating a function where I pass the url of the next_page but it doesn't work.

```
function callWatson(url) {
  let watson_url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api';
  if (!url) {
    watson_url = `${watson_url}/v1/workspaces/[workspace_id]/logs?version=2018-09-20`;
  } else {
    watson_url = `${watson_url}/${url}`;
  }
  assistant = new watson.AssistantV1({
    username: ************,
    password: ************,
    url: watson_url,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    version: '2018-09-20'
  });

  return assistant;
}

let input = [];
let pagination = [];

assistant.listAllLogs(param, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.logs.length; i++) {
      pagination.push(response.pagination);
      input.push(response.logs[i]);
    }
    // logger.debug(input);
    logger.debug(pagination);
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you just publish your credentials?

Comment: There is a python sample at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54220624/1167890

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs you need to use "next_url" - The URL that will return the next page of results, if any.

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant#pagination

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. I know that already but I am having issues passing the next_url in the subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `next_cursor` field from the `pagination` object in the current response as the value for the `cursor` parameter in the subsequent request.

Comment: How do I make a subsequent request?

Comment: Call `assistant.listAllLogs` again, and this time pass a value for the `cursor` parameter that you obtained from `pagaination.next_cursor` of the previous response.